# Generate 100 normally distributed random numbers in Python

Tags: python, loops, random

I am an extreme beginner in Python and I am having a difficulty writing a very simple code.

I am trying to write a simple code to generate 100 normally distributed number by using the function gauss with expectation 1.0 and standard deviation 0.005, and later store in an array that can be used to calculate the mean and standard deviation from those 100 sample.

Here is my code:

```
def uniformrandom(n):   
    i=0  
    while i< n:  
        gauss(1.0, 0.005)  
        i = i + 1
    return i
```

Then I tried

```
L = uniformrandom(100)
```

The code is supposed to be indented in Python but it is just when I typed in StackOverflow I didn't really know how to indent it.

Let say I use the formula (x1+x2+...+xn)/100 to get the mean, how can I store those numbers and use the formula to get the mean.

I tried the code in Python but L only prints the value n. I have little what is wrong with my code and how should I fix it.

If anyone could lend some help, it would be really appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Your code isn't properly indented

Comment: The `uniformrandom` function doesn't *return* anything, so `L` in your code is empty (contains only the `None` value).

Comment: You just undid Zondo's edit which fixed your indentation - careful when you're editing at the same time as someone else!

Comment: Yes, its my mistake @Useless

Comment: You increase `i` until it is equal to `n`, then return it.

Answer (score 7):

```
import numpy as np

L =np.random.normal(1.0, 0.005, 100)
```

here you can find documentation for normal distribution using numpy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

then you can calculate mean by using:
`my_mean_value = np.mean(L)`

you have to remember, that if you want to print something, you need to use `print my_mean value`

Answer (score 3):

`uniformrandom()` is not returning anything.  You need to add a `return` statement:

```
def uniformrandom(n):
    i=0
    while i< n:
        gauss(1.0, 0.005)
        i = i + 1
    return i
```

That is returning the *number* of `gauss`'s, though.  You aren't even storing the `gauss()` calls in a list.  You should change your function to this:

```
def uniformrandom(n):
    gausses = []
    for _ in range(n):
        gausses.append(gauss(1.0, 0.005))
    return gausses
```

You could even use a list comprehension:

```
def uniformrandom(n):
    return [gauss(1.0, 0.005) for _ in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 1):

> The code is supposed to be indented in Python but it is just when I typed in StackOverflow I didn't really know how to indent it.

You just indent using spaces.

> I tried the code in Python but L does not print anything.

Well, your function did not `return` any value.
**Edit** now your code returns an integer `i`, which will be the same as `n`. It still doesn't return anything to do with the `gauss` function you call.

For example, to generate a single suitable number:

```
def uniformrandom_1():
    return gauss(1.0, 0.005)
```

now, if you want a list of `n` numbers, you can just use

```
[uniformrandom_1() for i in range(n)]
```

or write that as a function:

```
def uniformrandom(n):
    return [uniformrandom_1() for i in range(n)]
```

> how can I store those numbers and use the formula to get the mean

---

OK, now we can translate your *mean* formula into

```
def mean(sample):
    return sum(sample)/len(sample)

L = uniformrandom(100)
LMean = mean(L)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,

```
def uniformrandom(n):  
   nums=[]
   total=0
   i=0  
   for i in range(1, n):
     num=gauss(1.0, 0.005)
     nums.append( num  ) 
     total +=num
  return (nums,total/n)
```

returns the generated numbers and the mean

Answer (score 0):

This will create a list with n random numbers using gauss.
import random as rd

```
def uniformrandom(n):  
    i=0
    random_list=[]*n
    for i in range(n):  
        random_list+=[rd.gauss(1, 0.005)]
    return random_list
```

to get the mean simply use `mean=sum(random_list)/n`

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate 100 normally distributed random numbers in Python by using the function gauss with expectation 1.0 and standard deviation 0.005, one can use [`numpy.random.normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) as follows

```
import numpy as np

random_numbers = np.random.normal(1.0, 0.005, 100)
```

In order to store the `random_numbers` in an array, one can do that with [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) as follows

```
random_numbers_array = np.array(random_numbers)
```

Then to calculate the mean use [`numpy.mean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)

```
mean = np.mean(random_numbers_array)
```

And to calculate the standard deviation use [`numpy.std`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) as follows

```
std = np.std(random_numbers_array)
```

A function, that takes as input the mean and std of the random number generator, and does what OP wants, can be something like

```
def uniformrandom(mean, std):
    random_numbers = np.random.normal(mean, std, 100)
    random_numbers_array = np.array(random_numbers)
    mean = np.mean(random_numbers_array)
    std = np.std(random_numbers_array)
    return random_numbers_array, mean, std
```

Let's see what it retrieves

```
print(uniformrandom(1.0, 0.005))

[Out]:
(array([1.00716042, 0.99938042, 0.99178698, 1.00791888, 1.00623344,
       1.00555578, 0.99890757, 1.00695046, 0.98482516, 0.9928371 ,
       1.00016377, 0.99510195, 1.00280951, 0.99472607, 0.99453582,
       1.00791222, 1.00302319, 1.00004503, 0.99884054, 1.00429994,
       0.99591756, 1.010769  , 1.00827643, 0.996754  , 0.99236853,
       1.00096622, 1.00092158, 1.00192217, 1.00148108, 0.9975529 ,
       1.00953799, 1.0073464 , 0.99942883, 1.0065139 , 1.00265884,
       1.00885268, 0.99613224, 1.00299541, 0.99977556, 1.01090735,
       1.00132776, 0.99711267, 1.00129545, 1.00500702, 0.99937595,
       1.00603761, 0.98960716, 0.99932355, 0.99687272, 1.00332839,
       0.991147  , 0.99643908, 0.99279811, 1.00112179, 1.00012058,
       0.9989405 , 1.00150169, 1.00683601, 0.99885708, 0.99632519,
       1.00112315, 0.99280336, 1.00759542, 1.00140661, 1.00183764,
       0.99540866, 1.0002343 , 0.99421579, 1.01169739, 1.00330142,
       0.99977923, 1.00365608, 0.9984007 , 1.00106568, 1.00349778,
       0.99527499, 0.99189253, 0.99477082, 0.99486919, 0.99784054,
       0.99240925, 1.00417557, 0.99566904, 1.00355492, 0.99717846,
       0.99910477, 0.99718301, 1.00711659, 0.99623698, 1.00143697,
       1.00876763, 1.0049953 , 0.99885742, 0.99498201, 1.00324752,
       0.99907905, 0.99762597, 0.99502917, 0.99511507, 1.00991401]), 1.0002981820807302, 0.005332038881947385)
```